# Error Handling for Instagram API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, error-handling, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to migrate from old to new Instagram API.
Graph API has this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling) for Error Handling but I can't find corresponding page for Instagram API.

I thought that both APIs use the same error codes but some Instagram API error codes are not documented in Graph API

for example:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/17841407629754967?fields=business_discovery.username(sdfsdf)%7Bid%2Cfollowers_count%2Cmedia_count%2Cbiography%2Cwebsite%2Cusername%7D&access_token="
```

response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid user id",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 110,
    "error_subcode": 2207013,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Cannot find User",
    "error_user_msg": "The user with username: sdfsdf cannot be found.",
    "fbtrace_id": "ChYJVqBQTRd
"
  }
}
```

Generally Instagram API Documentation looks very "poor". What do you think? Error Handling Page is hidden somewhere or is not published yet?

ps: solidarity to every developer who is affected from facebook recent changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this error means "non-business account". Non-business accounts are not accessible thru business discovery.
There exists a personal Instagram profile sdfsdf.

Comment: Thanks, and what is the endpoint to look up for "nornal" users?